# Меньшая ценность одной единицы игровой валюты

Tags: android, ios

Мой друг, не программист, а обычный android геймер, предлагает **сделать еденицу игровой валюты в несколько раз менее ценной**.

Т.е. если у вас в игре можно было бы:

1. за прохождение уровня получить **5** денежных единиц
2. супер шляпа, помогающая герою, стоила бы **30** д.е.
3. за 100 реальных рублей можно было бы купить **50** д.е.

То, согласно его идеи лучше было бы так:

1. за прохождение уровня получить **1000** денежных единиц
2. супер шляпа, помогающая герою, стоила бы **6000** д.е.
3. за 100 реальных рублей можно было бы купить **10000** д.е.

Обосновывает он это так:

> Заходит юзер в магазин, смотрит, **за 100 рублей можно только двухзначное количество монет купить. "Чё так мало" - думает он и не покупает**

или

> Заходит юзер в магазин, смотрит, **за 100 рублей можно аж пятизначное количество монет купить. "Вау, так много. Да это же почти халява!" - думает он и покупает**

Собственно вопрос: как вы относитесь к этой идее?

p.s. от себя добавлю, что если и в уже существующих играх ничего менять не стоит, то в новых очень даже стоит попробовать

p.p.s. кстати именно при таких условиях можно применить знаменитый трюк, так популярный в наших магазинах электроники - не 10000 руб, а 9990

Comment: я не понимаю трюк в магазинах, кучка 9 меня больше убивает чем 1 и 0. И мне кажется не в этом хитрость. Просто вот у меня редко есть 100 рублей на игру. пусть хоть лям д.е. будут за это давать. Вот еслиб я мог потратить 1 рубль и кратной ему цифре то это было бы юзабельней. я не хочу покупать за 100 рублей я хочу купить за 36, именно столько в данный момент я хотел бы потратить на игру.

Comment: У меня бы сложилось впечатление, что я в зимбабве в саааамом начале кризиса.

> Заходит юзер в магазин, смотрит, за 100 рублей можно аж пятизначное количество монет купить. "Вау, так много. Да это же почти халява!" - думает он и покупает

вау-эффект, конечно, есть, но он не такой большой, как кажется, и юзеры не настолько дураки в основной своей массе.

Comment: Логика юзера немного другая, чем вы себе представляете. Он заходит в магазин и смотрит, что ему понравится и смотрит на цену(30 или 6000 не важно). После этого он идет и узнает, сколько стоит купить игровую валюту и как ни крути, это будет 100р(50 или 1000 д.е.) на одну шляпу и чуть больше половины остается. Как итог, юзеру без разницы, но вы заставляете его считать тысячами, а не десятками, что для некоторых может быть не очень удобно.

Comment: @Biwara , не понимаете скорее всего потому что трюк цельнотянутый с запада, а у нас принято округлять и не очень следить за копейками и потому на не кажется что 999 это меньше 1000, то есть формально-то конечно меньше, но большинство людей нашего менталитета понимает что такой разнице можно пренебречь.

Comment: Что касается ценообразования и трюка в 9999 монет, можно почитать тут для справки: [приемы ценообразования](http://www.elitarium.ru/2011/08/12/priemy_cenoobrazovanija.html). В частности: 

> Неокругленные цены. Это цены, установленные ниже круглых сумм. 
> Покупатель склонен оценивать снижение цены более существенно, чем 
> реально. Например, если экономическая ценность товара составила 200 
> руб., то цена продаж в 199 руб. будет восприниматься покупателями 
> значительно более низкой, чем в 201. У покупателя также создается 
> впечатление, что фирма тщательно анализирует затраты и цены.

Comment: @Bimawa, касательно одного рубля, то скажу что по крайней мере у google play мин цена - 30 руб. Хотя опять же, для запада 30 руб это всего одна д.е., и для них она менее ценна, чем для нас 30 руб.

Может кто-нибудь скажет об уровне жизни, но я, когда был в европе, с 1 евро расставался легче, чем в России с 40 рублями

Answer (score 6):

Все нижеследующее общие соображения как игрока - разработкой именно игр мне как-то не пришлось заниматься

Я не думаю что именно в магазине будет серьезный эффект от большего числа нулей (мы все уже были миллионерами до 97 и знаем что не в числе нулей счастье :) ), но такой трюк позволит делать приток денег более частым в самой игре (условно говоря, на уровне будет можно выбить по монетке с каждого мелкого врага, а не одну мегамонету с промежуточного босса), а также поделить мегашляпу на отдельные части что сделает сборку всего предмета интереснее - интереснее взять сначала шляпу на +5, а потом к ней перо на +2 и пряжку на +3, чем сразу шляпу на +10, тем паче что первые +5 уже будут работать, когда у игрока только половина суммы, а вот полная шляпа на +10 при половине суммы не даст ничего т.к. ее еще не купить. Ну и можно играть например тем что шляпа в сборе на + 10 стоит 9000 но прям щас, а все предметы отдельно - 10000. А можно и наоборот, мы однажды так делали (или только собирались, не помню, опишу как будто делали)  с ИнАпами - выпустили полное открытие возможностей за 10 единиц, а все возможности по частям стоили 9, ну а потом был вброс - разрабы лохи и покупать отдельно дешевле

Comment: @aknew я вообще редко доначу... но вот эта игра высосала из меня кучу бабла: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dead-ahead/id594482571?mt=8 Если будет возможность проанализируйте ее плз ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с [@danpetruk](/users/8694/danpetruk):

> Может кто-нибудь скажет об уровне жизни, но я, когда был в европе, с 1 евро расставался легче, чем в России с 40 рублями

я тоже в европе с легкостью тратил 10 евро на обед, а дома, с такой же легкостью готов растоваться максимум на 150 рублей на обед.

Что на счет игр, то перегибать палку в ту или инную сторону не стоит.
Получить за 1 рубль - 1 миллион единиц - плохо, в процессе игры значит, человек увидит что за шляпу ему надо заплатить 500 тысяч единиц, его оттолкнет от доната.

Еще одна хитрость, делать несколько уровней единиц: медные монеты, серебряные монеты, золотые монеты (10.000 м.м. = 100 с.м. = 1 з.м.) а продавать можно серебряные и золотые монеты.